# how can I assign routing tables to interfaces which are configured via dhcp

Tags: networking, dhcp, routing

My host has two interfaces with both are DHCP configured.
I do need a default gateway for both interfaces and therefore routing tables with rules for each interface. So it would be good to get all dhcp based routing entries into the right routing tables

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ip route` command, but changes won't persist after reboot. If you want to make your changes persistent use `netplan`. [netplan examples](https://netplan.io/examples)
There are examples how to set static routes.